# Append an iframe and div to body

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, appendchild

I'm a newbie in Javascript. I'm trying to attach a div to the body and then an iframe to the div, i.e. an overlay, in which I would like to load a video. In IE10, neither appendChild works. Neither element is created. In IE11, the overlay is created, but the iframe is not.

Also, in Chrome and in IE11, the video opens in a separate tab--not in the overlay div. I've tried several variations with no success. 
Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<title>Events | NO</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var video = document.createElement("iframe");
    var overlay = document.createElement("div");
    $(".testimonial").click(function() {
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
    $(overlay).addClass("overlay");
    overlay.appendChild(video);
    video.name = "iframe_a";
    video.width = "600px";
    video.height = "400px"; 
    $(video).addClass("youtube-player");
    $(".overlay").show();
    $(".youtube-player").show();

    }); 

});
</script>
<style>

.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:50;
    color:#fff;
    display:none;
}

.youtube-player {
   left: 50%;  
   z-index:1000;
   width:600;
   height:400;
   display:none;
   left: 0; top: 0;
    height:0; width:0;
    border: none;

}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h2>NFC Events</h2>



<div class="events" style="width: 75%;">
<h3>August 2015</h3>
   <h4>Katrina Remembrance Program</h4>
    <p style="width: 55%;">Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
Blah Blah Blah Blah </p>

<ul>
<li><a class = "testimonial" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xJ0Z-ty61w0?wmode=opaque" 
target="iframe_a">Watch the video</a></li>

<li><a class = "testimonial" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rNM5HW13_O8?wmode=opaque" 
target="iframe_a">Watch the video</a></li>
</ul>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are appending the "Element" object and not the HTML of the object. Now using jQuery where you don't need the outerHtml. You also need to prevent default action on a tag so it won't launch in a new tab.

```
$(".testimonial").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
    $(video).prop("src",$(this).prop("href"));
    $(overlay).addClass("overlay");
    $(overlay).append(video);
    video.name = "iframe_a";
    video.width = "320px";
    video.height = "240px"; 
    $(video).addClass("youtube-player");
    $(".overlay").show();
    $(".youtube-player").show();
});
```

Let me know if you need more details. Example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/oor2pmhb/2/

Comment: I'm trying to have a video load in the iframe. I thought that outerHTML was for text.

Comment: No outerHtml will give you the HTML equivalent of you javascript element you created with document.createElement(). Let me see if I can get a sample for you. Stand by, unless another SO member posts one.

Comment: Working example added.